# Seaching in files using shell

Tags: shell

I want to create a list of words from multiple files. All files have keywords in them and a set of words in front of that.  For example:

```
Keywords: engine, motor, car, etc.
```

I want to make a list of all these words using a shell script.

*From the comments:*

It's a set of text files containing emails. Every file has a header which has a line like this:

```
Keywords: photo, camera, color
```

I want to build a sort of bag of words from these keywords. That is, in the end I would like to have an array of words.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the file syntax? Is it <keyword> <somethingelse...>" like "motor foo bar"?

Comment: I don't get the "a set of words in front of that" part. What's the input?

Comment: its a set of text files containing emails. Every file has a header which has a line like this: Keywords: photo, camera, color. I want to build a sort of bag of words from these keywords. That is, in the end I would like to have an array of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I really hope you mean a unix/linux based shell)

It will help in the future to get a reasonable answer if you edit your post to include examples of expected inputs (2 small sample files would be perfect) AND the output you need for you 'bag of words'. Also, you are allowed to use 5 tags on a question, so indicate basic OS  as unix/linux/Windows/other? and a possible programming language. Note that when you hover over a tag, you'll see how many followers there are. Don't waste valuable tags on something with only a few followers. (not that you have done that). The more followers, the more likely you will get someone that can help you.

That said, given the 2 data sets you have included in your original message and a comment, plus my best guess at 'bag of words' lead me to propose the following:

```
cat carFile
other stuff
Keywords: engine, motor, car
other stuff

cat cameraFile
other stuff
Keywords: photo, camera, color
more other stuff
Keywords: road, highway, oinker
final other stuff


awk '{
       if ($0 ~ /Keywords:/) {
         line=$0
         sub(/Keywords: /, "", line)
         array[FILENAME] = array[FILENAME] ? array[FILENAME] ", " line : line
       }
      }
      END {
        for (key in array) {
          printf("%s:\t%s\n", key, array[key])
        }
      }
      ' carFile cameraFile
```

output

```
carFile:        engine, motor, car
cameraFile:     photo, camera, color, road, highway, oinker
```

Note that I have deliberately put car terms in the cameraFile. The idea is that any file you include as an argument to the awk script is processed, and any line with 'Keywords:' is added to the list **based on the input filename**.

Note also that you could easily change the output, to just show the values that have been retrieved from Keyword lines (without displaying the sourceFile name) by eliminating that from the output processing in the END statement, like

```
       for (key in array) {
          printf("%s\n",  array[key])
        }
```

---

**some details on awk processing**

FILENAME is an automatically supplied awk variable that corresponds to the current file that is being processed.

array is a user defined name for a awk associative array. It could have been 'a' or 'arr' or any name that meets the variable naming convention for awk (the same as all C language derived var name rules).

sub( ... ) is the awk function for 'substitute'. I have copied the input line '$0' to a var called line, and then deleted the Keywords: part of the line.

awk processes data via an implicit loop with code that is inside the initial '{ ... }' block.

We scan for lines that are keywords with `if ($0 ~ /Keywords:/)` and then process only those lines in the conditional block.

The `END { ... }` block is 'run' only after all input files have been read. In this case, we cycle thru the array on the keys, and print out key value pairs. Because we appended data into the array values (line 5), you get both sets of keywords showing up for the cameraFile.